# Kubernetes: Deployment generation is 35, but latest observed generation is 34

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, rancher

I have a Rancher Kubernetes Cluster running and my application containing sevral pods is running as a helm chart. When I wanted to update my application, I updated my container image and redeployed the pod. Since 3 years, this worked well. Suddenly, when I try to redeploy my frontend pod, I get the following error message from the rancher gui:

**Deployment generation is 35, but latest observed generation is 34**

I googled the error and "deployment generation", but it seems umcommon to have this problem. There are almost no results from google, what makes me wonder...The pod is not getting deployed currently.

Does anyone has a hint on why this suddenly happens and how to fix that?

Thanks in advance,

Ben

Comment: The frustration is because there isn't much and efficient documentation available for RKE clusters. I had faced RKE issues earlier and the only thing I found out was that I had to go through the obsolete docs more than twice.

Comment: Is it something related to compatibility between rancher kubernetes version and the deployment yaml version?

Comment: Really hard to find proper documentation on this, indeed. I try to reboot everything. Maybe that works.

Comment: I'm seeing it on Rancher on an imported kubeadm deployed cluster...

Answer (score 0):

**Just need to pause and redeploy the deployment.**
It was due to consecutive failures of the deployment to try to be at a running state due to so internal errors of the app like the database being down or something else which was an internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

This might have been caused by a failed or incomplete helm upgrade etc.

possible solution to your issue:

1. list the charts and check status using `helm ls -n <namespace>`
2. after running above cmd, check status of your helm deployment - probably the status will be failed.
3. `helm history <chart-name> -n <namespace>` - lists the past helm revisions
4. Rollback to an earlier version that was working :- `helm rollback <chart-name> <revision-version> -n <namespace>`.

The above should revert back your chart to an earlier working version and possibly clear this error. Atleast this worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the exact solution to this, but I had to reboot the whole cluster to get rid of this message and regain the ability to deploy. Seems to be something really odd.